# UWP Custom Constructor when creating a secondary window

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm developing a quick application with the sole purpose of using picture-in-picture mode (compact view) in UWP to display Youtube videos over top of my work. Here's the way the current system works:

MainPage - Handles searching of youtube videos
YoutubeItem - A usercontrol that the mainpage creates for each youtube result. Approximately 50 of these are put into a wrap panel.
YoutubeViewer - A seperate page that runs in it's own window and displays the youtube video.

Here's my issue. I store all the information for the youtube video in each of the YoutubeItems. Using a button, I record the click event and handle it. Here's the code for handling the click:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
        int newViewId = 0;
        await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Frame frame = new Frame();
            frame.Navigate(typeof(YoutubeViewer), null);
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
            Window.Current.Activate();

            newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;

        });
        bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
    }
```

The problem arises when I have to send the link for the video to the YoutubeViewer. Originally, I was doing this through a constructor but upon using this method for the Windows Documentation, I am unable to use my own constructor from my knowledge. How would you folks recommend getting the link to the new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways. 
the simplest, though not necessarily the most elegant, is to create a new class that inherits from `Frame`and add to it a property for the link. Something like this:

```
public class FooFrame: Frame
{ 
       public string Link; 
}
```

then in your code assign it upon initializing the frame:

```
FooFrame frame = new FooFrame(){Link = "youtube.link.com"}
```

Comment: Sorry for the silly question. How exactly would I access this new property once I have created the new window. I believe the frame is a container for the page but I'm not 100% sure. I just came from WPF so sorry for the silly questions haha.

Comment: Make the property public. Then access it by doing something like frame.Link. If you're getting it from the page's container, then because you know its type, you can cast it into a fooFrame and then access the Link property.